# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined at handleChange , Cannot read property 'props' of null at handleSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i am new to react-redux stack , i am learning the basic , i am stuck now . i want save the form data in mongodb , but nothing happing . i am getting these two error , plaese help how to insert these form data into database. thanks in avdance

this is my form.js page. i sent data to action.js page from here , then to server.js and then to controller.js where i take import the model and trying to save the data.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import Messages from '../Messages';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import saveBasicUser  from '../../actions/basicAction';


class BasicUser extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {

      super(props);


      this. state = {

            username : '',
            address : '',
            phone : '',
            date : '',
            billing : ''



           }
      }



  handleChange (e) {

      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  }



  //========================================================================

  handleSubmit(e) {


    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.saveBasicUser({ username, address, phone, date, billing });


  }

  //========================================================================


  render() {


    var divStyle = {
      padding: '16',
    };





    return (
      <div className="container ca-container">

        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
              <h1> ADD basic USER</h1>

            <hr/>

            </div>
            </div>




          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

          <label > Name : </label> 



          <input className= "form-control"  id = "username" name = "username" value={this.state.username}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}  />

          <label > address : </label> 


          <input className= "form-control" id = "address"  name = "address" value={this.state.address}
                      onChange={this.handleChange} />

          <label > Phone No: : </label> 


          <input className= "form-control"  id = "phone" name = "phone" value={this.state.phone}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}/>

          <label > Subscription date : </label> 


          <input className= "form-control" id = "date"  name = "date" type ="date" value={this.state.date}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}/>

          <label > Billing : </label> 


          <input className= "form-control" name = "billing" id = "billing" value={this.state.billing}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}/>

          <hr />           

          <button type="submit" value= "submit" className="btn btn-success btn-lg">Submit</button>

          </form>


          </div>


    );
  }
}


export default connect (null , {saveBasicUser})(BasicUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your `handleChange` and `handleSubmit` functions to `BasicUser` otherwhise `this` will be `undefined`. There are many way to do it, but the easiest in your case is to use function as class property (with arrow function to preserve class scope).

```
handleChange = e => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}

handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.saveBasicUser({ username, address, phone, date, billing });
}
```

This syntax is brought by ES7, you'll may need [this babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) to use it.

Another simple way if you don't want to install plugins is to use arrow functions inside `render()` :

```
<input onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />
```

Comment: `<input onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)} />` can be `<input onChange={this.handleChange} />`

Comment: It is not the same thing , if you do `onChange={this.handleChange}` you have to be sure your function this.handleChange is binded to the class instance. {e => this.handleChange(e)} is auto-binded with its parent because of the arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

Put these two lines in the constructor.
You aren't using babel I think or something which is why you can't use arrows.

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this;
```